# In the Page Object Model, why do we use Webelements instead of Strings as class variables?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Simply put: when implementing the POM framework we have Pagefactory initialize all the elements in a pageobject. Why do we do this instead of storing the xpath/css selectors as strings and calling those as needed instead?

ex:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//Button[text()='Add and Edit']")
@CacheLookup
private WebElement addAndEdit;
```

vs

```
private String addAndEdit;
```

Comment: Show us a minimal code example.

Comment: Sorry, added a short example of the declarations at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

This is not defined as part of the page object model, this is defined by `PageFactory` which is a helper class in initializing elements in a page object. The intent there is to set up a proxy so that the element's location strategy is defined by the `@FindBy` and you can reference the `WebElement` and it will go look it up for you when you use the reference.

If you are going to store locators, don't store a string... store instead a `By` locator. It has the extra information of the *TYPE* of locator, e.g. By.id, By.cssSelector, etc. I think this is much cleaner approach and will prevent you from having to somehow determine what type of locator that string variable is. This is the approach I use in all the Selenium projects that I have written and/or maintain.

According to the Selenium contributors, `PageFactory` should not be used. See [this yt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyfUpOysIF8&t=1519s) of Simon Stewart, Lead Committer, stating don't use it (27:26) and so on and why. The link starts the section that leads into his comments on `PageFactory`.